# Tool for pop-up notifications in corner of the display or in taskbar tray

Tags: windows, command-line, notification

Could you recommend a Windows tool which can show custom notifications in corner of the screen (or at its edge) which I can control through the command line or through API?

So I'm seeking my own way to create kind of notification bubbles with custom information popping from corner of the screen.

I have tested growl so far but it <del>has</del>`was 2-3 years ago and that time I experienced in some of its features` poor performance on Windows. It also had serious problems with control via COM/API.

Optional but welcome features include:

- message queue (handles more messages in queue)
- custom skin
- custom icon/image
- COM or other API interface

Comment: What OS(es)? do you need support for. I would have suggested Snarl for Windows which is one of the Growl ports

Comment: @NickWilde - I'd appreciate if you transfer your post into an answer. Also I have re-checked Growl, maybe I'll give it one more sight.

Comment: Sure will do - didn't post as an answer because of your comment about Growl.

Comment: @NickWilde - I've edited the comment about Growl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally been using [Snarl](http://snarl.fullphat.net/) lately.  I've predominantly been just using built and I haven't done any low level custom notifications so far; I have done custom notifications through the [Grunt-Nofity](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify) plugin for [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Responsiveness and appearances I've quite liked although I did disable a *lot* of the built in updates - because at least on a laptop which I power off regularly being notified that I had disconnected/reconnected to each network is yucky (especially when you are using mutliple Virtual Machine sessions with their own fake network adapter). However enabling/disabling them was quite easy so that is not a significant downside to my mind - sure I'd like to have a tinsy bit saner of automatic setup but it isn't a problem really.

It has quite a bit of easily setup/[built in notifiers](http://snarl.fullphat.net/content/whats-included/)/[supported apps](http://snarl.fullphat.net/content/supported-apps/).

In regards to your extras:

- *message queue (handles more messages in queue):* hmmmm... not sure exactly what you mean but it can handle many messages at the same time if that is what you are thinking.
- *custom skin:* I *think* so; but you may only be able to do global styling rather than individual notification specific styling. [Information about styling](https://sites.google.com/site/snarlapp/dev#TOC-Styles) and the [available styles](https://sites.google.com/site/snarlapp/addons/styles) would probably be a good starting point for developing your own style(s).
- *custom icon/image:* [Recommended](https://sites.google.com/site/snarlapp/developers/developer-guide#TOC-Title-and-Text).
- *COM or other API interface:* [Yes](https://sites.google.com/site/snarlapp/developers/developer-guide#TOC-Introduction); in fact it has both an activeX/COM library, a whole slew of different language specific libraries and if that wasn't enough you can also send JSON formatted notifications from within browsers or use [GNTP](https://sites.google.com/site/snarlapp/gntp).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is the usage  of **notifu**:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go: http://alternativeto.net/software/growl-for-windows/?platform=windows

So, these are some alternatives:

- [Snarl](http://snarl.fullphat.net/) - is a Growl port. I don't know about a notification queue, but I do know that it supports a lot of programs. It has an [API and custom skins](http://snarl.fullphat.net/content/wtf/).
  Here a selection of what is included 'in the box': http://snarl.fullphat.net/content/whats-included/.
- notifu. Not as extensive as Snarl, but maybe all the better because of that. According to [AlterniveTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/notifu/about/?platform=windows) it uses the same API as Windows to display notifications. So the notifications will look the same as the default windows one.
  Official website seems to be [paralint.com/projects/notifu](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/), but McAfee SiteAdvisor marks the website as unsafe. Look on the website at your own risk! (but you probably already have, looking at your answer)